# Type of clause and correct usage in this example

Tags: clauses, parsing

It follows two sisters— **one is devoted to her faith, the other breaks the community's strict rules.**

What would we class this type of clause ?  (one is this, the other is this)

What part is the main clause ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a "comma splice", but a fairly harmless one. Each part is a complete sentence, but the two sentences are linked. By splicing the two sentences with a comma the author indicates that they should be read and understood together.  You could punctuate differently using a semicolon to avoid the splice:

> It follows two sisters:  One is devoted to her faith; the other breaks the community's strict rules.

Comma splices are generally considered to be poor punctuation and should be avoided, but this one is fairly harmless.

Comment: Particularly in informal writing